# How to make a working SQL query a native query in spring data

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, nativequery

I created an SQL query:

`SELECT ORDER_NUM, STUFF2, STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (STUFF3 = 'poor') 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)`

The query works correctly and I get the desired result; However, I am now trying to use this working query in my spring data application as a native query, using the `@Query` annotation.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ORDER_NUM, STUFF2, STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (STUFF3 = ?0) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)", nativeQuery = true)
List<eOrder> findByStuff3(String stuff3);
```

I copied the exact same query and placed it in my repository (*as shown above*) but the value is binding as NULL and no records are showing. Is there a step that I am missing to make this query work with my spring application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through further research I was able to fix the problem I was having. The native query I used in my repository actually does work, there was a simple error in the code, instead of a `0`, I replaced with a `1` and it worked great!

***Old version:***

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ORDER_NUM, STUFF2, STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (STUFF3 = ?0) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)", nativeQuery = true)
List<eOrder> findByStuff3(String stuff3);
```

***Modified version:***

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ORDER_NUM, STUFF2, STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (STUFF3 = ?1) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)", nativeQuery = true)
List<eOrder> findByStuff3(String stuff3);
```

I also came across another method that also works just as well using **JPQL** I was able to get my query to run in my spring application:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t1.ORDER_NUM, t1.STUFF2, t1.STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (t1.STUFF3 = ?0) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)", nativeQuery = true)
List<eOrder> findByStuff3(String stuff3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to this:

@Query(value = "SELECT ORDER_NUM, STUFF2, STUFF3 FROM table1 t1 WHERE (STUFF3 = :stuff3) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ORDER_NUM FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM)", nativeQuery = true)
List findByStuff3(@Param("stuff3") String stuff3);

Comment: You need to add and import for Param:

import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;